# gSoap multiple calls with SSL enabled

Tags: c++, web-services, webservice-client, gsoap

what is the efficient way to call a WS multiple times in gSoap with SSL enabled.
I have this code:

```
SimpleInterfaceHttpPostProxy proxy(SOAP_IO_CHUNK | SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE | SOAP_C_UTFSTRING | SOAP_C_NILSTRING );

    proxy.soap->ssl_flags = SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION;
    proxy.soap->connect_timeout = TIMEOUT_CONNECT;
    proxy.soap->send_timeout = TIMEOUT_SEND;
    proxy.soap->recv_timeout = TIMEOUT_RECV;
    proxy.soap->socket_flags = MSG_NOSIGNAL;

    e__ResultAndString rsp;

int retCode = proxy.CheckChanges("someurl","/checkpath","serialnumber",&rsp);
proxy.destroy();
```

Now if i want to call proxy.CheckChanges and reuse SSL session and reuse connection i should probably change it to:

```
while(true)
{
  retCode = proxy.CheckChanges("someurl","/checkpath","serialnumber",&rsp);
  proxy.destroy();
}
```

If i do so, the second call always timeouts! If i don't use proxy.destroy(); it works... But does this generates memory leaks?

I mean there are a lot of examples how to use gSoap all made in main, but none that i could find that would reuse proxy/stub and make multiple calls.

So can someone please for others sake :) for the future explain how to make FAST efficient and without memory leak, calls to WS. Which approach is correct, i would like to reuse tcp connection or atleast reuse SSL session in almost 15sec calls.

Thank you!

Comment: Nobody uses multiple calls ? :D

Comment: We are having the same issue - did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No have no idea how to solve it, did you find anything?

Comment: nope, we simply create a new proxy on each call which is inefficient:(